# Chrome extension to safari extension (Safari not showing popup)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, safari-extension

In chrome and firefox extension is working as expected.
Problem with safari :  Convert chrome extension to safari extension. Extension allows to login in safari browser. But dos not show pop up as it is showing in chrome.

1. Covert chrom to safari extension ==>x crun safari-web-extension-converter /Users/{username}/Desktop/Projects/browser-extension/dist

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My answer should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your Chrome extension to Safari extension. Then you use this command in your Terminal:

```
xcrun safari-web-extension-converter /path/to/extension
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/converting_a_web_extension_for_safari

However, take a look at the working Popup example at Apple developer documentation. The sea create. That have a working popup wit this as manifest.json (Manifest V2) code:

```
"browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/toolbar-icon-16.png",
            "32": "images/toolbar-icon-32.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
```

You can download the Safari extension zip file on this web page:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/developing_a_safari_web_extension